# Use check_call to convert dot to png, get no such file or permission denied

Tags: python, subprocess, png, dot, treemodel

I'm using

```
check_call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png'])
```

but I got

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot'

When I specify the path to replace the `'dot'` I got

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I used import os to check my current working directory, it is correct.
Why it still says no such file?

Comment: Can you run the command from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I just tried in terminal. I tried to specify directory and set the directory, I got same errors as I got in Jupyter

Comment: Then your problem is unrelated to the Python code. It looks more like a graphwiz installation issue.